# jQuery Slider/Carousel update content after DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys.

I have searched for an jquery slider/carousel plugin where i can update your content after DOM-ready, with AJAX call or something like that. Anyone knows an plugin where this is possible? Add new jquery slide after her ready?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCarousel handles that just fine. See the "Dynamic Content Loading" section here: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Comment: They have a few example links on the same page.